# java FileReader BufferedReader "FileNotFound"

Tags: java, file-io

My Reading-Program spits out an "FileNotFound" exception, any ideas?

Code Snippet :

```
import java.io.FileReader;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class Main{

    public static void main (String [] args){


try{

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));

    String[] input = new String[0];
String[] temp = new String[1];

for (int i = 0; (br.readLine()) != null; i++){

     for(int j = 0; j < (i); j++){

          temp[j] = input[j];

         }

     temp[i] = br.readLine();
     input = new String [i + 1];

     for(int j = 0; j <= (i); j++){

          input[j] = temp[j];

     }

     temp = new String[i + 2];
}

br.close();

    } catch (IOException error1){
    System.out.println("Error 404: File Not Found");
}

}
```

Now the code is Compilable but spits out the "Error 404: File Not Found", although the "file.txt" is in the same folder as the "class" file. Why is that?

Comment: Simply because it could not find the file. Is the file path valid ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the following statement before creating BufferedReader

```
System.out.println(new File(args[0]).getAbsolutePath());
```

and check that the outputed path actually points to and existing file on your filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to say, as you haven't provided a path to the file or anything, but try going for the absolute path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a file structure like this

```
C:/
   My_IDE_Projex
              ProjectRoot
                       bin
                          Main.class
                       src
                          Main.java
```

If you're using the realtive path "myFile.txt" from the command line, If you compiled your java file from the command line, wherever you specified the class file to be compiled to, that's where you need to have the file. For example:

> `C:\My_IDE_Projex\ProjectRoot\bin> java Main myFile.txt`

The file should be in the bin folder